# How to change properties panel layout

Tags: interface, customization, panel

I've watched information of new 2.9 changes and noticed that UI is more friendly. I've downloaded version 2.9 and I still can't get what I saw.

I Googled but didn't find anything. I have added an image of what I want to change.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure about running 2.9?

Comment: Hello :). You still have 2.8* opened, not 2.90. Notice the small arrows to reorder modifiers, they were dropped in fhe latest release.

Comment: The right layout I saw in "whats new in 2.9" on Blender site when They write about "unsubdivide and rebuild". The left layout is from 2.90. I thought that there is something wrong with my 2.90 if its different that what is shown on blender website. I didnt noticed that 2.83.2 had it the same as on "whats new". It's quite confusing.

Comment: These changes in modifiers UI indeed can make older versions' UI seem more friendly

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved.
New features are shown on blender.org on older version. It confused me.
[image]

I feel so stupid. Sorry for taking Your time.
[image]

Thanks for responses

Best Regards